# Ajuda em Binding C#

Tags: c#, string

Eu tenho este seguinte código:

```
private void DataGrid_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var i = 0;
    var d = DataContext as TicketExplorerViewModel;
    if (d == null) return;

    var entityTypes = d.EntityTypes.Select(entityType => new DataGridTextColumn
        {
            Header = entityType.EntityName,
            Binding = new Binding("[" + entityType.Id + "]"),
            MinWidth = 60,
        });

    foreach (var dgtc in entityTypes)
    {
        DataGrid.Columns.Insert(i + 1, dgtc);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Dentro de `Binding = new Binding("[" + entityType.Id + "]"),`

Eu preciso inserir uma string ou variável  para pegar um campo personalizado.

Não sei como exatamente proceder para fazer isto, tentei algumas formas que conheço, mas tive diversos erros, alguém para ajudar?

Obrigada!

Comment: Vc disse que teve erros, poderia postar eles aqui?

Comment: Olá #gato, obrigada por responder, os erros foram vários mais eu percebi o motivo, eu que não estou conseguindo criar um Binding )=. E não sei como proceder, não entendo como Binding funciona exatamente, mas estou estudando para entender.

Comment: Da uma olhada [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228539/how-to-bind-list-to-datagridview) que talvez lhe ajude.

Comment: Muito Obrigada! Consegui!

Comment: @AnaFreitasTelles Se puder, poste como resposta a solução que encontrou. Desta forma poderá ajudar outros a mesma dúvida ou relacionadas.